# Django on Heroku, uploading files with gunicorn

Tags: django, heroku, gunicorn

I am trying to allow users to upload files for a django app running on heroku and am running into some issues. In my development environment (using the django development server), I have it set up to allow users to upload files (a small image/logo). Everything is working great.

When I try to run it on heroku or even on my development server using gunicorn (instead of the django development server), users are unable to upload files. I know generally it is best to use something like Amazon S3, however since the files are relatively small I thought starting directly on heroku might work.

I understand that I can get uploaded files to work with manage.py collectstatic, however this isn't the issue as the uploaded file never actually gets uploaded. I do not notice any errors that I can see.

Is what I am trying to accomplish practical? Should I be focusing on trying to get this to work with S3 instead? It seems a little daunting for my needs now but I am open to suggestions or help of any kind.

Thanks,

Edit:
It appears that it only works outside my virtual environment. It doesn't matter if gunicorn is being used or not inside the virtual environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should be focusing on something like S3 as an external store to assets created during your program execution yes.  Heroku uses an [ephemeral filesystem](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-isolation#ephemeral_filesystem) for each dyno, so that certainly won't be the place to upload the files, even if they are small.